# Which rewrite rules are required for this cgit instance (on shared hosting)?

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting, cgit

I have cgit installed on shared hosting and although the home page comes up, every url comes up with file not found until I add cgit.cgi to the front of the path.

e.g `www.domain.com/path` will error unless typed in the browser as `www.domain.com/cgit.cgi/path`, yet all the links in the returned page are in the form `www.domain.com/path`.

Is there some rewrite rule for .htaccess that can cause the webserver to treat every instance of `www.domain.con/path` as `www.domain.com/cgit.cgi/path`? Drupal's Clean URLs come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule path cgit.cgi/path
```

Comment: I have tried something along those lines but I don't think I am using the right syntax? What is the variable or placeholder that should replace path in the formula?

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*) /cgit.cgi/$1` This will rewrite every instance of www.domain.con/path as www.domain.com/cgit.cgi/path